# Finding JSONPath value by a partial key

Tags: jsonpath

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "Dialog_1": {
      "en": {
        "label_1595938607000": "Label1",
        "newLabel": "Label2"
      }
    }
}
```

I want to extract "Label1" by using JSONPath. The problem is that each time I get a JSON with a different number after "label_", and I'm looking for a consistent JSONPath expression that will return the value for any key that begins with "label_" (without knowing in advance the number after the underscore).

Comment: Don't know if this can be done with jsonpath, but it can be done with jq.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with JSONPath. `EL` or `Expression Language` does not have sch capability.

Besides, I think you need to review your design. Why the variable name is going to be changed all the time? If it is changing then it is `data` and you need to keep it in a variable. You cannot keep `data` in `data`.